# Error Providing Service in Lazy Loaded Module (Angular 6)

Tags: angular, angular6

I have a lazy loaded module (`LazyModule`) and a service to be provided in its scope (`LazyModuleService`).

When using `@Injectable({providedIn: LazyModule})` for the `LazyModuleService` class, Angular compiler throws a `No Provider` error as soon as I inject `LazyModuleService` in any child component of `LazyModule`.

However, when I remove `{providedIn: LazyModule}` from the decorator and instead add `providers: [LazyModuleService]` to the `@NgModule` decorator of `LazyModule`, my app compiles and works without errors or warnings.

According to the [relevant section](https://angular.io/guide/providers#providedin-and-ngmodules) of angular.io, both solutions should work, not just the latter.

Please advice.

Comment: Were you able to resolve this?

Comment: Haven't checked since then. I just put all my services into the providers array of the host module.

Comment: @ArneWolframm any updates on that one? having the same issue here and would rly like using the tree shaking ability using `providedIn`..